# TableView not updating

Tags: xcode, swift, calendar, tableview

I'm currently struggling with getting my TableView to update *after* I finish performing some functions called in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear. I tried using self.tableView.reloadData() at the end of my viewDidLoad but it didn't work and upon reloading the tab, the app would crash.

Here is some of my code (I'm trying to fetch events from a Google Calendar and display it in a TableView). I'm trying to display an array of strings named listOfEvents and it is being populated *after* the tableView is already loaded.

I also tried adding self.tableView.reloadData() at the end of my fetchEvents() but it also killed my app upon reloading the tab

```
class CalendarViewController: UITableViewController {

var listOfEvents: [String] = []

private let kKeychainItemName = "Google Calendar API"
private let kClientID = "clientID"

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials by
// resetting the iOS simulator or uninstall the app.
private let scopes = [kGTLAuthScopeCalendarReadonly]

private let service = GTLServiceCalendar()
let output = UITextView()

// When the view loads, create necessary subviews
// and initialize the Google Calendar API service
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let auth = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.authForGoogleFromKeychainForName(
        kKeychainItemName,
        clientID: kClientID,
        clientSecret: nil) {
            service.authorizer = auth
    }
}

// When the view appears, ensure that the Google Calendar API service is authorized
// and perform API calls
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if let authorizer = service.authorizer,
        canAuth = authorizer.canAuthorize where canAuth {
            fetchEvents()
    } else {
        presentViewController(
            createAuthController(),
            animated: true,
            completion: nil
        )
    }
}

// Construct a query and get a list of upcoming events from the user calendar
func fetchEvents() {
    let query = GTLQueryCalendar.queryForEventsListWithCalendarId("primary")
    query.maxResults = 10
    query.timeMin = GTLDateTime(date: NSDate(), timeZone: NSTimeZone.localTimeZone())
    query.singleEvents = true
    query.orderBy = kGTLCalendarOrderByStartTime
    service.executeQuery(
        query,
        delegate: self,
        didFinishSelector: "displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:"
    )
}

// Display the start dates and event summaries in the UITextView
func displayResultWithTicket(
    ticket: GTLServiceTicket,
    finishedWithObject response : GTLCalendarEvents,
    error : NSError?) {

        if let error = error {
            showAlert("Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        var eventString = ""

        if let events = response.items() where !events.isEmpty {
            for event in events as! [GTLCalendarEvent] {
                let start : GTLDateTime! = event.start.dateTime ?? event.start.date
                let startString = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(
                    start.date,
                    dateStyle: .ShortStyle,
                    timeStyle: .ShortStyle
                )
                eventString += "\(startString) - \(event.summary)\n"

                // An array holding all my upcoming events
                listOfEvents.append("\(startString) - \(event.summary)")
                print(listOfEvents)
            }
        } else {
            eventString = "No upcoming events found."
        }
        output.text = eventString
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}


// Creates the auth controller for authorizing access to Google Calendar API
private func createAuthController() -> GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch {
    let scopeString = scopes.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    return GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(
        scope: scopeString,
        clientID: kClientID,
        clientSecret: nil,
        keychainItemName: kKeychainItemName,
        delegate: self,
        finishedSelector: "viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:"
    )
}

// Handle completion of the authorization process, and update the Google Calendar API
// with the new credentials.
func viewController(vc : UIViewController,
    finishedWithAuth authResult : GTMOAuth2Authentication, error : NSError?) {

        if let error = error {
            service.authorizer = nil
            showAlert("Authentication Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        service.authorizer = authResult
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

// Helper for showing an alert
func showAlert(title : String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
    )
    let ok = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        handler: nil
    )
    alert.addAction(ok)
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(self.listOfEvents.count)
    return self.listOfEvents.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Events Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var event = ""
    event = listOfEvents[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = event

    return cell
}
```

}

I would appreciate any help and insight :-) Thanks so much!

Comment: You should enter your code as text instead of an image. After output.text = eventString, you should reload the tableview. Let me know if that works.

Comment: sorry about that I changed it to text. Unfortunately, putting it after output.text = eventString didn't do the trick for me and caused it to crash upon boot :-(

Comment: You should remove your clienID. Don't want someone else using it. Does it crash if you don't reload the tableview? Does it show blank?

Comment: thanks for the tip :-) if i don't reload the tableview, it doesn't crash but it does come up as blank. Upon debugging, I think that the reason it is blank is because it populates my array after the tableview has already been made

Comment: Upon more debugging, your answer worked! Thanks for your help! :) would select your answer if i could but it's in the comments :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After output.text = eventString, you should reload the tableview.